# It's possible share a disk between two diskgroups after limit the disk space in ASM?

Tags: oracle, oracle-asm

I am not able to get a new disk in the moment and I was woldering if it's possible to share a disk between two diskgroup.

I have a FRA diskgroup with a disk of 200gb and I need to add 100gb in DATA diskgroup.

I have limited FRA disk to 100g:

```
alter diskgroup FRA resize all size 100g;
```

Then, the free space would be allocated in nother diskgroup (DATA). Is there a way to do it in ASM? I have tried in my lab, but I get the error:

`alter diskgroup DATA add disk 'ORCL:DATA_STB3' size 100g;` (ORCL:DATA_STB3 is the disk where now I have 100gb free).

```
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-15032: not all alterations performed
ORA-15029: disk 'ORCL:DATA_STB3' is already mounted by this instance
```

If it's not possible, why can we limit ASM disk size? what situation this command is userful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reducing the size of an ASM disk, you can reduce the size of the underlying disk device at OS (and storage) level. You can not just use the remaining free space on the ASM disk presented as another ASM disk in another (or in the same) diskgroup.

If you want to use separate sections of the same disk device differently, first you need to present them as multiple disk devices at OS level (you can just create partitions or LVM volumes on that single disk), and use those separate disk devices as ASM disks in ASM diskgroups.

If you really want to do this, first drop the ASM disk from the FRA diskgroup (too bad this is the only disk there if I understand correctly, so you may not be able to do this), remove the ASMLib metadata with `oracleasm deletedisk`, create separate devices for the sections on the underlying disk device (create partitions or LVM volumes on that single disk), restamp the newly created separate devices with `oracleasm createdisk`, then add the newly stamped separate candidate ASM disks in the ASM diskgroups.

It may be simpler not to do this at all now just to revert it later, instead of this, you could move/recreate some database files in the FRA diskgroup temporarily.